# How to toggle Symfony's php-translation/symfony-bundle EditInPlace

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I followed this [documentation](https://php-translation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symfony/edit-in-place.html#building-your-own-activator) for **Edit In Place**, and setup the *Activator*, and it works!

However, I will be using this on the production site and allowing access via a `ROLE_TRANSLATOR` Authorization.  This is also working, but I don't want the web interface always "on"

**How would I go about enabling it via some sort of link or toggle?**

*My thoughts*, it would be simple to just add a URL parameter, like `?trans=yes` and then in the activator;

```
return ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted(['ROLE_TRANSLATOR']) && $_GET['trans'] == 'yes');
```

Obviously, `$_GET` would not work, I didn't even try.

1. How do I generate a link to simply reload THIS page with the extra URL parameter
2. How do I check for that parameter within the "Activator"

or, is there a better way?

Comment: I think I may scrap this question, maybe, but I belive this is what I am looking for [referencing-services as Twig global Variables](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services) Now I just need to learn more about how services work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this, as I have discovered more about "services" is to do the logic diectly in the [RoleActivator.php](https://php-translation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symfony/edit-in-place.html#building-your-own-activator) file.

referencing documentation for [How to Inject Variables into all Templates via Referencing Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services) I came up with the following solution;

*src/Security/RoleActivator.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException;
use Translation\Bundle\EditInPlace\ActivatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class RoleActivator implements ActivatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;
    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface
     */
    private $translate;
    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $request;
    private $params;
    private $path;

    private $flag = null;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker, TranslatorInterface $translate, RequestStack $request)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->translate = $translate;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkRequest(Request $request = null)
    {
        if ($this->flag === null) { $this->setFlag($request); }
        try {
            return ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted(['ROLE_TRANSLATOR']) && $this->flag);
        } catch (AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getText()
    {
        if ($this->flag === null) { $this->setFlag(); }
        return ($this->flag) ? 'linkText.translate.finished' : 'linkText.translate.start'; // Translation key's returned
    }

    public function getHref()
    {
        if ($this->flag === null) { $this->setFlag(); }
        $params = $this->params;
        if ($this->flag) {
            unset($params['trans']);
        } else {
            $params['trans'] = 'do';
        }
        $queryString = '';
        if (!empty($params)) {
            $queryString = '?';
            foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
                $queryString.= $key.'='.$value.'&';
            }
            $queryString = rtrim($queryString, '&');
        }
        return $this->path.$queryString;
    }

    private function setFlag(Request $request = null)
    {
        if ($request === null) {
            $request = $this->request->getCurrentRequest();
        }
        $this->flag = $request->query->has('trans');
        $this->params = $request->query->all();
        $this->path = $request->getPathInfo();
    }
}
```

*config\packages\twig.yaml*

```
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        EditInPlace: '@EditInPlace_RoleActivator'
```

*config\services.yaml*

```
services:
    # ...
    EditInPlace_RoleActivator:
        class: App\Security\RoleActivator
        arguments: ["@security.authorization_checker"]
```

So What I added over and above the php-translation example is the `getText` and `getHref` methods and corresponding `private` variables being set in the `checkRequest` and read there after.

Now in my twig template (in the header) I just use

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_TRANSLATOR') %}
    <a href="{{ EditInPlace.Href }}">{{ EditInPlace.Text }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Add the new keys to the translation files and your done. the `trans=do` query parameter is toggled on and off with each click of the link.  You could even add toggling styles with a class name, just copy the `getText` method to something like `getClass` and return string `a` or `b` with the Ternary.